# Executing msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail via ADO from within Excel's vba

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, ado

I'm trying to run the following:

```
Sub sendMailViaADO()

Dim cmdStoredFunct As ADODB.Command
Dim r As ADODB.Recordset

Dim strConn As String
strConn = _
    "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
    "P-----D=xxxxx;" & _
    "PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;" & _
    "USER ID=yyyyyy;" & _
    "INITIAL CATALOG=xxxxx;" & _
    "DATA SOURCE=xxxxx;" & _
    "USE PROCEDURE FOR PREPARE=1;" & _
    "AUTO TRANSLATE=True;" & _
    "CONNECT TIMEOUT=0;" & _
    "COMMAND TIMEMOUT=0" & _
    "PACKET SIZE=4096;" & _
    "USE ENCRYPTION FOR DATA=False;" & _
    "TAG WITH COLUMN COLLATION WHEN POSSIBLE=False"

Set c= New ADODB.Connection
c.ConnectionString = strConn
c.CommandTimeout = 0
c.Open

Set cmdStoredFunct = New ADODB.Command
Set cmdStoredFunct.ActiveConnection = c
Set r = New ADODB.Recordset

With cmdStoredFunct
    .CommandText = "msdb..sp_send_dbmail"
    .CommandText = adCmdStoredProc

    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@recipients", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, "me@me.co.uk;")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@subject", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, "xxx")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@body", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 50, "yyy")

    Set r = .Execute
End With

'>>>
'>>>is there another way like the following ?
'Dim sTemp1
'sTemp1 = "{call msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail('me@me.co.uk', 'xxx', 'yyy')}"
'>>>


If Not (cmdStoredFunct Is Nothing) Then
    Set cmdStoredFunct.ActiveConnection = Nothing
    Set cmdStoredFunct = Nothing
End If
If Not (c Is Nothing) Then
    If (c.State And 1) = 1 Then c.Close
End If


End Sub
```

It is erroring on the execute command `Set r = .Execute` with this message:

[image]

Looks to me like it is finding the stored proc ok but that the string it is using is causing this mysterious exception.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem, but it looks like you're missing the dbo in `msdb..sp_send_dbmail` which would be `msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail`

Comment: Is there any reason you are sending mails via SQL Server? Have you considered using a command line tool like `BLAT`, or using any number of SMTP VBA libraries to do this instead? Then there is no SQL Server involved. For example you can do the above in `BLAT` in one line in a batch file without having to connect to a database

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for info - we have sql-server installed - so no need for me to install any third party tool. I think I'm very close in the code I have posted in the question - can you help to answer it?

Comment: Firstly note: because you are using additional layers (VBA, ADO and SQL Server) your solution has uneccessary complexity and you are having issues even getting your code to run. I have always had issues using the ADO Command object so I end up actually building a string with the full `EXEC` in it and open that in a `RecordSet` object. Would you consider that option? You might also want to use SQL Profiler to observe what is being submitted to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example if you want to avoid using a command object:

```
Dim sSQL as String

sSQL = 
    "EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail  " & _
      @recipients='me@me.co.uk'," & _
      @subject='xxx'," & _
      @body='yyy'"

Call r.Open(sSQL,c)
```

People will huff and puff about SQL injection but thats the least of your worries.

Comment: I will see if this works and then if it does I can go back to the original question and try to suss that.

Comment: I was able to get the original approach to work. I need to explain in an answer of my own. Unfortunately both approaches had to be binned in the end due to permissions which prevent direct execution of this msdb stored procedure.

Comment: Dare I say it... another reason not to involve SQL Server in sending an email.

Comment: Well I think sending emails from sql-server is more controlled than via the outlook object model.

Comment: 'more controlled' is a very general comment. IMHO sending emails from a feral excel application by any means (SQL, Blat or whatever) is uncontrolled

Comment: 'feral' - strange adjective to use? "living in the wild but descended from domesticated individuals..". 'Excel' is one of the planet's most used pieces of software - why shouldn't it send out emails?

Comment: I mean this kind of feral: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feral_information_systems All systems are built in some kind of larger context. In some contexts Excel is perfect for the job  in others it isn't

Comment: ....this was going to be quite independent (althgough condoned by management) but it now runs a stored proc which UPDATEs our centralised email control table on sql-server, which is in turn scanned every few minutes, via a stroed proc run by the agent, for new emails that need to be sent. I am BCC'd on all mails leaving via this route and all details of emails are stored in this central table. So, I suppose, it has ended up being part of a bigger system context.

Comment: haha although I am all for 'legitimate' solutions it sounds like a tech head has got in on this and posed an overcomplicated solution... you know what else has a outgoing email queue and a record of all emails sent... the SMTP server itself! Anyway I'm genuinely pleased you found a solution and all the best in future.

Comment: (it was me - guilty as charged!) I don't have any rights to look in the exchange server so this solution is next best thing. I'll add solution later - thanks for help Nick